# Access CoreBluetooth CBPeripheral In Two Apps Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

After a little tweaking with CoreBluetooth in iOS, and writing a basic data reading app from a Bluetooth heart rate monitor, I have grown a great curiosity to whether or not two or more applications can simultaneously read data from a corebluetooth device.

With my little knowledge I have tried to open a sample app from RayWenderlich and run mine at the same time, however, only one appears to be able to discover the device at a time. This makes sense, however, on the off chance that this is possible, it would be nice to know.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: the bluetooth keyboard works with every app simultaneously, so logically the actual active application can access to the specific periphery, no matter which other apps are in the background.